# Python Django with MongoDB with Hadoop

Tags: django, hadoop, mongodb

For my Final year project I have to make a big data application. So far the sketch of the overall project includes these three ( Django, MongoDb, Hadoop ).
But I am not sure they will work together like a ecosystem.

Python Django works with MongoDb, and MongoDb can work with Hadoop.
As far as MongoDb documentation, Hadoop can fetch, process and output back from MongoDb.
Python Django can work as a front-end for MongoDb. In this way I visualize data stored in MongoDb in the python web framework.

Does this recipe can cook me the application I am looking forward to?